# How can 120V fail to spin an AC motor that spins fine with 120V on a different power source?

Tags: motor, ac-motor

While troubleshooting a home appliance, I found something odd: a 120V AC refrigerator fan stopped spinning despite being connected to 120V AC voltage (verified with my multimeter) inside the refrigerator. But when I hard-wired the fan to a 120V household circuit, the fan runs fine.

I checked the usual culprits (e.g. shorts, corroded connectors, mechanical obstructions) and everything looked OK. Just to verify, I mounted the hard-wired fan inside the appliance and it ran fine. Then I switched back to the refrigerator's connectors and it wouldn't run, and I re-verified 120V AC across its connectors.

My assumption is that the appliance's controller board (or some other upstream electrical component) failed and caused this problem.

What could cause this behavior? My naive understanding was that if the voltage is present, then current will flow. Could the upstream electronics be doing something that prevents current from flowing (at least enough current to overcome the friction of the fan motor) but still shows the 120V AC voltage difference?

Comment: Could be something upstream limiting the current to the fan.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I think is happening here. But wondering exactly how that works, given Ohm's law?

Comment: Multimeters draw next to zero current when measuring a voltage across two contacts; that's why your able to measure the 120V. But when you connect a more significant load like a fan, it will draw much more current from those contacts.

Comment: *if the voltage is present, then current will flow* The power connection must be able to provide the current required, too.

Comment: I'd try replacing the fan. Old fans tend to get gunked up, and are harder to get spinning from rest. Your fridge isn't able to provide enough current to fan. Your wall outlet is.

Comment: @earl - yep, understood. What I'm wondering about is what's happening upstream that results in current being limited? My naive understanding was that motors draw *more* current when they're stopped, implying that a stopped motor has lower impedance. So how does the upstream component prevent current from flowing in this case?

Comment: Are you seeing the 120V when the motor is connected and not running?  If you disconnect the load, you can easily measure that much leakage with most voltmeters.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis - yes

Comment: When does the fan start, at the same time as compressor, or with a delay, or is it temperature controlled?

Comment: That should read When does the fan *usually* start, if you know.

Comment: @MiNiMe - I believe that the fan should be running all the time, or at least all the time when the compressor is running. But I'm not sure, given that I only started paying attention to it after it failed. :-)

Comment: Should be when the compessor runs, that's when heat needs to be removed. If both are supposed to start simultaneously, that's where you get a voltage drop that prevents the fan from starting. Question remains, is it the fan that is out of spec, or what else. I just speculate here, there's a capacitor wired to the compressor, these age and might impact the compressors ability to start, maybe the fan too.

Comment: I would look carefully at the connections.  The motor runs on a makeshift direct connect, but not with the internal connection.  Either the problem is between the 120V measurement and the motor terminals, or the motor on/off is controlled in a different way by the controller.